# How to access a value within a nested struct

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

I'm having trouble getting a certain value when I make an API call. The structs are set up like so:

```
struct Status: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let results: [Results]
}

struct Results: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let abstract: String
    let url: String
    let multimedia: [Multimedia]
}

struct Multimedia: Decodable {
    let imageUrl: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case imageUrl = "url"
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to get the `imageUrl` member of the `Multimedia` struct. When I make the data request, I populate an array `var storyData = [Results]()` with the `object.results`. I make the data request in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
    fetchData(url: jsonURL) { (result: FetchResult<Status>) -> (Void) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let object): self.storyData = object.results
            print("\n\nNumber of stories: \(self.storyData.count)\n\nStories: \n\n \(self.storyData)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error decoding JSON: \n\n \(error)")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to get the `imageUrl` so I can display the image in a table view, and I thought I'd get it in my `cellForRowAt` method using something like

```
let newsStories = storyData[indexPath.row]

cell.storyImageView.cacheImage(urlString: newsStories.multimedia.imageUrl)
```

However I can't do this, I can access `newsStories.multimedia` but no further, as if `multimedia` doesn't have any properties.

Is there a different way that I can get the `imageUrl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multimedia] is an array, you have to access it through an index. Then you can access it with imageUrl.

For Example:

```
cell.storyImageView.cacheImage(urlString: newsStories.multimedia[0].imageUrl)
```